# MySQL Function for calculating Haversine Distance

Tags: mysql, function, distance, haversine

all.

I want to create a mysql function that calculates the haversine distance between two geo-code.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION haversineDistance
                 (
                  lat1 VARCHAR(256), 
                  long1 VARCHAR(256), 
                  lat2 VARCHAR(256), 
                  long2 VARCHAR(256)
                 )
 RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN

      DECLARE radLat1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLong1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLat2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLong2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE dLat FLOAT;
      DECLARE dLong FLOAT;
      DECLARE cordLength FLOAT;
      DECLARE centralAngle FLOAT;
      DECLARE distance FLOAT;

      SET radLat1 = CAST(lat1 AS FLOAT) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLong1 = CAST(long1 AS FLOAT) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLat2 = CAST(lat2 AS FLOAT) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLong2 = CAST(long2 AS FLOAT) * PI() / 180;
      SET dLat = radLat2 - radLat1;
      SET dLong = radLong2 - radLong2;
      SET cordLength = POW(SIN(dLat/2),2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*POW(SIN(dLon/2),2);
      SET centralAngle = 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(cordLength), SQRT(1-cordLength));
      SET distance = 6367 * centralAngle;

      RETURN distance;
 END
```

But I got an error like this;

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help us help you if we knew what line 4 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

Solved it.

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION haversineDistance
                 (
                  lat1 VARCHAR(256), 
                  long1 VARCHAR(256), 
                  lat2 VARCHAR(256), 
                  long2 VARCHAR(256))
 RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN

      DECLARE radLat1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLong1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLat2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE radLong2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE dLat FLOAT;
      DECLARE dLong FLOAT;
      DECLARE cordLength FLOAT;
      DECLARE centralAngle FLOAT;
      DECLARE distance FLOAT;

      SET radLat1 = CAST(lat1 AS DECIMAL(10,10)) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLong1 = CAST(long1 AS DECIMAL(10,10)) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLat2 = CAST(lat2 AS DECIMAL(10,10)) * PI() / 180;
      SET radLong2 = CAST(long2 AS DECIMAL(10,10)) * PI() / 180;
      SET dLat = radLat2 - radLat1;
      SET dLong = radLong2 - radLong2;
      SET cordLength = POW(SIN(dLat/2),2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*POW(SIN(dLon/2),2);
      SET centralAngle = 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(cordLength), SQRT(1-cordLength));
      SET distance = 6367 * centralAngle;

      RETURN distance;
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're getting an error, due to the semi-colon characters present as line delimiter in your function.

To explain it further, directly quoting from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

> By default, mysql recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter,
>   so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass
>   the entire stored program definition to the server.

This means that you must override the default delimiter temporarily for your program to compile. Enacapsulate your program between

```
DELIMITER $$
   your code for function
$$
```

and then give it a try.

EDIT:
You can change back the delimiter by specifying the default delimiter again

```
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```